# Set contrasts in glm

Tags: r, effects, glm, contrast

I have binomial count data, coming from a set of conditions, that are overdisperesed. To simulate them I use the beta binomial distribution implemented by the `rbetabinom` function of the `emdbook` `R` package:

```
library(emdbook)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(p = rep(runif(3,0,1)),
                 n = as.integer(runif(30,100,200)),
                 theta = rep(runif(3,1,5)),
                 cond = rep(LETTERS[1:3],10),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
df$k <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) rbetabinom(n=1, prob=df$p[x], size=df$n[x],theta = df$theta[x], shape1=1, shape2=1))
```

I want to find the effect of each condition (`cond`) on the counts (`k`). 
I think the `glm.nb` model of the `MASS` `R` package allows modelling that:

```
library(MASS)
fit <- glm.nb(k ~ cond + offset(log(n)), data = df)
```

My question is how to set the contrasts such that I get the effect of each condition relative to the mean effects over all conditions rather than relative to the `dummy` condition `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: (1) if you want contrasts relative to the mean, use `contr.sum` rather than the default `contr.treatment`; (2) you probably shouldn't fit beta-binomial data with a negative binomial model; use a beta-binomial model instead (e.g. via `VGAM` or `bbmle`)!

```
library(emdbook)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(p = rep(runif(3,0,1)),
             n = as.integer(runif(30,100,200)),
             theta = rep(runif(3,1,5)),
             cond = rep(LETTERS[1:3],10),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 ## slightly abbreviated
 df$k <- rbetabinom(n=nrow(df), prob=df$p,
                    size=df$n,theta = df$theta, shape1=1, shape2=1)
```

With `VGAM`:

```
 library(VGAM)
 ## note dbetabinom/rbetabinom from emdbook are masked
 options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))
 vglm(cbind(k,n-k)~cond,data=df,
        family=betabinomialff(zero=2)
        ## hold shape parameter 2 constant
 )
 ## Coefficients:
 ## (Intercept):1 (Intercept):2         cond1         cond2 
 ##     0.4312181     0.5197579    -0.3121925     0.3011559 
 ## Log-likelihood: -147.7304
```

Here *intercept* is the mean shape parameter across the levels; `cond1` and `cond2` are the differences of levels 1 and 2 from the mean (this doesn't give you the difference of level 3 from the mean, but by construction it should be (`-cond1-cond2`) ...)

I find the parameterization with `bbmle` (with logit-probability and dispersion parameter) a little easier:

```
 detach("package:VGAM")
 library(bbmle)
 mle2(k~dbetabinom(k, prob=plogis(lprob),
                   size=n,  theta=exp(ltheta)),
      parameters=list(lprob~cond),
      data=df,
      start=list(lprob=0,ltheta=0))
## Coefficients:
## lprob.(Intercept)       lprob.cond1       lprob.cond2            ltheta 
##       -0.09606536       -0.31615236        0.17353311        1.15201809 
## 
## Log-likelihood: -148.09
```

The log-likelihoods are about the same (the VGAM parameterization is a bit better); in theory, if we allowed both shape1 and shape2 (VGAM) or lprob and ltheta (`bbmle`) to vary across conditions, we'd get the same log-likelihoods for both parameterizations.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the std. error of cond3? or would it simply be the sum of the std. errors of cond1 and cond2?

Comment: Not quite, you need the covariance too.  It would be `sqrt(var1+var2-2*cov(1,2))`; unfortunately most of the convenience packages  and methods (predict with std errors, lsmeans, effects package) don't work in this case ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. A related question. In my experiment n are counts of cells and k are counts of the cells in which the a virus which I infected that cells with integrated into the genome (and hence is giving a detectable signal), and the conditions are different cell types. Suppose part of my dispersion is due to technical variability (rather than biological variability) of the infection, for which I have empirical control data for each cell type (again, k's and n's). How can I subtract that technical variability from the dispersion in the beta binomial model I'm fitting to the real data?

Comment: nothing obvious springs to mind. Try asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Effects *must* be estimated relative to some base level. The effect of having any of the 3 conditions would be the same as a constant in the regression.

Since the intercept is the expected mean value when `cond` is = 0 for both estimated levels (i.e. `"B"` and `"C"`), it is the mean value only for the reference group (i.e. `"A"`).

Therefore, you basically already have this information in your model, or at least as close to it as you can get.

The mean value of a comparison group is the intercept plus the comparison group's coefficient. The comparison groups' coefficients, as you know, therefore give you the effect of having the comparison group = 1 (bearing in mind that each level of your categorical variable is a dummy variable which = 1 when that level is present) relative to the reference group.

So your results give you the means and relative effects of each level. You can of course switch out the reference level according to your presence.

That should hopefully give you all the information you need. If not then you need to ask yourself precisely what information it is that you're after.